# Error while renaming folder to revert back to original name in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

The line of code below throws a EPERM error with errno: 4048 on windows

```
fs.rename('/code/App/temp/tmp', '/code/App/temp/temp', (err) => {

    if (err) return console.log(err);

});
```

Actually i used the code (with altered paths) to rename the last folder from 'temp' to 'tmp' earlier and it succeeded.

The same set of permissions exist for that folder before and after renaming it.

why does it fail when i run code to revert back to the original name ?

Comment: Unfortunately, we won't be able to help you. The code itself is fine, so it's something environmental. Double-check the permissions of the `/code/App/temp/tmp` and `/code/App/temp` folders, check to see if there may be a pending operation in progress on `/code/App/temp/tmp` (in some file systems, that would prevent it being renamed; not in others), etc., etc. FWIW, I copied your code, swapped the names, created the structure, ran it, then swapped the names back and ran it, and provided the permissions were okay, it worked. Good luck!

Comment: Some process is probably locking the folder. [https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows)

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. i will revert if i find something.

Comment: Update: it works fine now. i have no idea why it gave the error yesterday. must be a process locking the folder as Moritz mentioned.